# UseStandardPrice field when import PricebookEntry

Tags: data-loader, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

I’am going to insert the prices for my products, but i’m not sure about how setup (true or false) the field UseStandardPrice of the object PricebookEntry.

I have found this :

> **UseStandardPrice field:**  FALSE means you will use the Unit Price from
>   the custom Price Book and NOT the Unit Price from the Standard Price
>   Book. TRUE – this option only works if this Product has been added to
>   the Standard Price Book. This choice will use the Unit Price from the
>   Standard Price Book

I don’t understand  where i will use the unit price selected with the UseStandardPrice field.

Why do i need to make this choise now, if when i will add the product to the opportunity i will make a choise with the button “CHOOSE  PRICEBOOK”.

What will be the the DefaultPrice on the product object?
Thanks in advantage.

Comment: I'd set it to False, I believe it still defaults to the Standard Unit Price, but you can override it.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, there is one Standard Pricebook and there are many custom Pricebooks.  This allows you to do the following:

- For SKU xyz, the standard pricebook price could be $10.00
- For the same SKU xyz, on the pricebook called Commercial, the price is $10.00
- For the same SKU xyz, on the pricebook called US Government, the price is only $8.00

When you create a pricebookEntry for the junction between Product2 and Standard Pricebook, set `useStandardPricebook` to `false`.  All pricebookEntries on standard Pricebook have `useStandardPrice` = `false`

When you create a pricebookEntry for the junction between Product2 xyz and Pricebook US Government, set `useStandardPricebook` to `false` and set unitPrice to 8.00.

On custom pricebook called 'Commercial' where SKU xyz is $10.00, then when you create a pricebookEntry for the junction between Product2 xyz and Pricebook Commercial, set `useStandardPricebook` to `true` and set unitPrice to 10.00.

In effect, your updates to PricebookEntry are mimicing the SFDC Force.com user interface where you define standard pricebook prices for a Product and then, if you use custom pricebooks, you can choose to use the standard price or override the standard price, just for that pricebook.

Don't forget that all pricebook entries must be inserted against the Standard pricebook before you can insert pricebookEntries on custom pricebooks.